# Android: why Chronometer.setText is not showing any text?

Tags: android, chronometer

I want Chronometer to display my timer. When `Chronometer.stop` is called, i want to stop timer and display text at same place.

Timer is getting stopped but after stopping when i try to

```
setText("Stopped");
```

It is not working.
Please let me know if i'm doing valid things or not.

**XML changes:**

```
     <Chronometer android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

**Code changes:**

```
        mTimer = (Chronometer) mRootGroupView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

On two buttons i'm starting and stopping timer.

```
      mTimer.stop();
      mTimer.setText("stopped"); 
      mTimer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      mTimer.setTextColor(color.red);
```

Please HELP !!!

Comment: You might want to post more code since everything looks good at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Problem was at setting color, thats why it wasnt displaying text at all (as if text is set to invisible)

modified code to :

```
      //mTimer.setTextColor(color.red);
      mTimer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

It started working, I donno why it was giving problem.
red color is defined in res/values/colors.xml.

Comment: I had similar problem - chronometer showed text only when touched where I supposed it could be drawn. Setting it any color solved the problem.